# Does Ontario have an Islamic Heritage Month?

Tags: canada

There were reports from [October 2016](https://www.thestar.com/news/canada/2016/10/06/october-is-now-islamic-heritage-month-in-ontario.html) that October would be made Islamic Heritage Month for Ontario, but looking at [Ontario’s celebrations and commemorations](https://www.ontario.ca/page/ontarios-celebrations-and-commemorations) there's no mention of it. I haven't found any reports of the idea being dumped - I'd expect some complaining and/or gloating if that did happen. So what's happened? Have they just forgotten to update their website?

Comment: I can't confirm this, so posting as comment, not answer, but it looks like that website is indeed behind the times. The link from Hindu Heritage month shows that should now be for November, while https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/16i20 deals with Islamic Heritage Month. It looks like someone noticed the potentially embarrassing clash http://www.ontla.on.ca/web/bills/bills_detail.do?locale=en&BillID=4296&detailPage=bills_detail_the_bill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [bill](http://www.ontla.on.ca/web/bills/bills_detail.do?locale=en&BillID=4200&detailPage=bills_detail_the_bill) was proposed in the Ontario legislature to proclaim the month of October as Islamic heritage month. This bill has received royal assent and is now a law.

Additionally, the bill mentions that

> In 2007 the Government of Canada declared the month of October in each year as Canadian Islamic History Month.

So October has been Islamic History Month in the entire nation of Canada for a decade and it is also now Islamic Heritage Month in Ontario.

Comment: Are you sure that http://www.ontla.on.ca/web/bills/bills_detail.do?locale=en&BillID=4200&detailPage=bills_detail_the_bill doesn't supercede the bill you found?

Comment: @origimbo I think you are correct, I just didn't find that. I've update

Comment: Should the last paragraph have "Islamic History Month ... Islamic Heritage Month" rather than two "Islamic Heritage Month"s? (They both start with "H", so I don't blame you for the mistake)

Comment: I misread the bill a bit. Ontario has a _Heritage_ month. Canada has a _History_ month. I've updated.